# Connection Refused Laravel 5.2 and Amazon S3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I am trying to upload/retrieve files from Amazon S3 using Laravels FileSystem.

I have setup an Amazon S3 account and created a new user using IAM. I've given the user the policy of `AmazonS3FullAccess`.  I have generated the the keys and copied the access and secret key.

I've added the keys to the file system config along with the region `Frankfurt` and my bucketname. I've also set the default disk to `s3`.

When i try to simply upload a file to the `S3` disk I'm getting an error.

```
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('S3_KEY'),
        'secret' =>  env('S3_SECRET'),
        'region' =>  env('S3_REGION'),
        'bucket' =>  env('S3_BUCKET'),
    ],
```

Php:

```
Route::get('s3', function() {
    Storage::put('myfile.txt' , 'Test File');
});
```

Error:

```
Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://s3.frankfurt.amazonaws.com/bucketnamehere?prefix=myfile.txt%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: Error creating resource: [message] fopen(https://s3.frankfurt.amazonaws.com/bucketnamehere?prefix=myfile.txt%2F&amp;max-keys=1&amp;encoding-type=url): failed to open stream: Connection refused
[file] /var/www/ProjectNameHere-Events/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php
[line] 312
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points I noticed from the HTTP request, you need to add the correct parameters in your `.env`

```
S3_REGION=eu-central-1
S3_BUCKET=CORRECT_BUCKET_NAME
```

I noticed from the endpoint that the bucket name is incorrect, unless you have changed for security.

Comment: My S3_Region=Frankfurt, should it be eu-central-1 where did you get this value from?

Comment: Yes, please find it here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: thank you, after adding the correct region it worked

Comment: Glad to help on that